# Can blocks created via the admin UI be cached?

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

I am trying to understand if blocks created using the admin UI can be cached or not? I had a look at the `block` table in the database and it would appear that the cache value is set to `-1` regardless of whether block caching is enabled or not.  So I am assuming that blocks created via the admin UI cannot be cached.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter might be what you are looking for.